# Explicit Hamel basis for an infinite dimensional Banach space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Does there exist an explicit example of an algebraic basis in a Banach space with infinite dimension? By "explicit", I mean a basis that can be constructed without using the axiom of choice for chosing the basis elements.

I know that such a basis must be uncountable and that for **some** Banach spaces it can be shown that there is no such "explicit" basis.

Comment: I suspect no such example is known.  Indeed, I suspect there is no example (established in ZF) of an infinite-dimensional Banach space that has a Hamel basis.

Comment: @GEdgar This really blows my mind. This just means that if we have any explicit uncountable set (like $\mathbb{R}$) and take the free vector space $F$ over this set, then we can't ever define a norm on $F$ such that $F$ is complete w.r.t this norm.

Comment: The answer is yes if one looks beyond Banach spaces and considers more general locally convex topological vector spaces. Take the space of almost finite sequences with the finest locally convex topology.

Answer (score 1):

In the article

> Wright, J. D. Maitland. All operators on a Hilbert space are bounded. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 79 (1973), no. 6, 1247--1250.

it is shown that in ZF + DC + BP the following is a theorem:

> Let $X$ be a F-space. Then $X^* = X'$, i.e. the algebraic dual is the topological dual.

If we could find a set $S \subseteq X$ and prove that $S$ is an algebraic basis in ZF, then I think we could obtain in ZF + DC an unbounded linear functional by taking $$T\frac{s_n}{||s_n||} = n \quad \text{for}\quad n \in \mathbb{N}\,,$$
where $\{s_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subseteq S$ is a countable subset, which would contradict the above theorem.